# How does Google Translate handle audio streaming for "Translate by Audio"

Tags: javascript, python, django, audio-streaming

How to best way to stream microphone data from browser to server and are there any documentation about how does Google handle this topic?
As an example in case: "Translate by Audio" in Google Translate.

I use Django web framework in the backend,  behind a Nginx reverse proxy and I would like to process microphone data coming from browser.

Open for suggestions.
Thx!

Comment: the only way is to use JavaScript because in browser only JavaScript may have access to microphone/webcam. I don't know examples for audio but few times I wrote answers how to stream webcam from browser to server and later back from server to browser.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please provide what you have tried